# Two column CSS layout and columns inside box

Tags: html, css

I want to make two columns page with box one (box1) and box two(box2). Then just after h2, I want to make two columns inside box2 with box2.1 and box2.2.

Here is my HTML code

```
<body>
  <div id="box1">
  <h1>Here is the box one.</h2>
  </div>

  <div id="box2">
  <h2>Here is the box two.</h2>

      <div id="box21">
      <p>Here is the box2.1</p>
      </div>

      <div id="box22">
      <p>Here is box 2.2</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is my CSS part.

```
#contentLeft{
float:left;
width:300px;
```

After that, I have no idea what to do. Tried number of ways, it didn't work. Could you please help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help you:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box1">
  <h1>Here is the box one.</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="box2">
  <h2>Here is the box two.</h2>
      <div id="box21">
      <p>Here is the box2.1</p>
      </div>
      <div id="box22">
      <p>Here is box 2.2</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#box1{
    float:left;
    widht:50%;
    background:#FF0000;
}
#box2{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:#00FF00;
}
#box21{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:#0000FF;
}
#box22{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    background:#e4e4e4;
}
```

Just for your reminder, don't use `dot(.)` in id or class name. You can also simplified the **CSS** by using the same class name in all div.

```
.box{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

OR the following code:

```
#box1, #box2, #box21, #box22{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

See the example : http://jsfiddle.net/N4hMw/2/

Comment: Thanks @Arif. I remember dot(.) is used to select class and using it as id name is not a good idea. Thank you.
I will try this code :)