# menu with two columns - each having different layout (boostrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I want to build a nav menu. I want it to be tall, and I want to split it horizontally in two. Then I want the left part to have something aligned to the bottom of the menu. The right part should have the nav links and be middle-aligned. I want to use as less css as possible. (I am also working with Angular Material and Bootstrap if that helps). Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/IfR5KslDszFGEg7sqcsd?p=preview). I have already checked out this [checkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267859/two-column-css-layout-and-columns-inside-box) but I am looking for another option.

```
<div class="menu container-fluid">
    <md-toolbar class="md-tall">
      <div class="container">
        <div layout="row">
          <!--Left-->
          <div layout="row">
            <md-button aria-label="Settings" class="shownSm">
              <ng-md-icon icon="menu" ng-click="main.small =!main.small" style="fill: #fefefe;"></ng-md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <div layout="column">
              <span flex></span>
              <span>
                  <small>Some name</small>
                </span>
              <span>
                  <small>Something else</small>
                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <span flex=""></span>
          <!--Right-->
          <div class="right" layout="column">
            <span flex=""></span>
            <div layout="row" class="hiddenSm">
              <ul class="text-center">
                <span><a href="#/">Item1</a></span>
                <span><a href="#/">Item2</a></span>
                <span><a href="#/">Item3</a></span>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
  </div>
```